# IIS issue with redirectting to Login Page in sub folder instead of root folder

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have an application deployed on IIS on server for testing. There is a main domain on IIS say www.abc.com and it has multiple separate web applications under it. 
e.g. there is an application, say xyz, running under www.abc.com i.e.
www.abc.com/xyz/Login.aspx
You can see that there is a Login.aspx page on root in xyz. (Remember xyz is itself a web application under www.abc.com domain).
Now xyz has a folder, AutoUpdate, which has also a Login.aspx page. If someone tries to access pages under Autoupdate folder, it must be redirected to the Login.aspx page under Autoupdate, but in the above mentioned hierarchy, it redirects the user to Login.aspx which exists in root folder.

However if I deploy that application, xyz, files under different domain directly, i.e. www.cde.com then it works perfectly and redirects the user to Autoupdate Login.aspx page if someone accesses the Autoupdate pages without authentication.

It is strange issue, not sure, if this issue is raising because of hierarchy of web applications in a single domain.

Comment: Have you checked the web.config of your root website www.abc.com?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood what should I need to check specifically there?

Comment: Check for Forms Authentication with LoginUrl

Comment: could you please share your application url and if you implement url rewrite rule?